# Add style : max-width for image in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor4.x

[image]

I want to auto add properti max-width:100% for image in Ckeditor.

but when i submit and save after that this properti disappeared.
I want to custom it. 
Thanks All
Best Regards

Comment: Hello @wake and Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure to follow up on the following how-tos [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do not post pictures or link to pictures of code, paste the code in and format it as such.

Comment: Add your code as inline text, not as a link to an image

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should do that not exactly when making content with ckeditor, but **after submitting** this html and **before saving** it.

*For example by utilize scraping libraries or by handle searching for
*img* in ready ckeditor html code, you can make some manipulations with 'style' attribute then.*

---

Another approach - is to override *img* objects styles by some stylesheets on page, where you want to show the ckeditor content.

.html

```
<div id="content">
    **ckeditor html**
</div>
```

.css

```
#content img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

---

Maybe you can of course do changes on ckeditor side by figured out with ckeditor plugins or overriding config, but it can cost unexpected problems.